# Intentional link between Ares' "armistice which cannot hold" and real Treaty of Versailles?

Tags: analysis, dc-extended-universe, wonder-woman

In the Wonder Woman movie, Ares makes a statement towards Diana, that he promotes an armistice which cannot hold. This sounds like an obvious reference to the real Armistice of Compiègne, a de-facto German surrender, and the imposed Treaty of Versailles. Supported by the fact that Ares turns out to be Sir Patrick Morgan, trying to negotiate an armistice. But at the end of the film, no further references are made. Is anything known if there was a reference planned in the film, or if more direct references were removed?

Versailles laid ground for demands of massive "reparations" by Germany, for up to 70 years into the future. A similar extortion by Germany against France in 1871 lasted only three years, with the sum a tiny fraction of post WW1 demands against Germany.

Speculation: It's notable that the film comes with heavy anti-German views (as opposed to Captain America), not towards the Nazis as classic supervillains, but in fact equating imperial Germany of WW1 to later Nazi Germany. The movie warms up the Belgian Atrocities propaganda, which was actually spread in WW1, and included mostly fabricated horror stories of mass rape, babies impaled with bayonets, cannibalism, arbitrary murders and the like, in occupied Belgium. Actual violent acts and war crimes, associated with guerilla, or franc tireur, warfare, were greatly exaggerated. Showing Belgian villagers enslaved (fleeing after a year of immobile trench battles?) and finally having a new poison gas tested on them, seems to directly build on this propaganda. This might be a reason why more obvious, critical references to Versailles were taken out.

Comment: Wow... thank you. I was actually looking forward to seeing WonderWoman, but after reading your last paragraph, I don't think I can stomach the "evil enemy" propaganda and will pass. At least Hydra of Captain America was "blatantly fictional"...

Comment: Well... Its true I've noticed they exaggerated Germany's evilness in this movie, but I think its worth to take notice that the whole war was "puppeteared " by Ares and it clearly states that the British high ranked officers didn't care much for the soldiers lives.

Comment: @LeonX: Still, stories of mass rape and impaled babies, puppeteered or not, is not exactly what I want to have shoved in my face when I sit down with popcorn and soda to enjoy some escapism.

Answer (score 7):

It's a little unclear what exactly you're asking here, but I think underneath this all I see the question as: "Is anything known if there was a reference (of the real Armistice of Compiègne) planned in the film, or if more direct references were removed?

As for references being removed we've heard directly from the director, Patty Jenkins: ["Wonder Woman’ Doesn’t Have a Single Deleted Scene"](http://collider.com/wonder-woman-no-deleted-scenes/). So, there is no evidence of a reference being cut.

As for the statement Aries makes, it's likely the writers and director felt that was all the reference that was needed, any more reference to future conflicts would have likely diluted the current conflict of the movie.